# Is there a term for the way that 'th' is pronounced differently in 'thin' and 'this'?

Tags: phonology, terminology

The point of the example in the question in the title is that, to my knowledge, there are no minimal pairs that contrast [ð] and [θ] in English, yet, if someone pronounced a word with those sounds correctly we would think it sounds wrong or at least think they must be using a different dialect than us. It is not free variation, and it is not phonologically conditioned.

I believe 'x' and 'ng' also behave this way in English, although in these cases we are dealing with two segments, always with 'x', and sometimes with 'ng'. Actually it is not about the orthography, so I should probably talk about [ks]/[gz] and [ŋ]/[ŋg]. You can correct me if I am wrong, but I don't know of any words that contrast only on these sounds. In this case there my be some phonological motivation for [ks] vs [gz]. I haven't thought it through. I know in the case of 'ng' there is some morphological motivation, but I think that would still qualify for the phenomena I am asking about.

I am studying a language which has prenasalized many words that begin with voiced consonants, but some words do not get prenasalized. I don't believe there are any minimal pairs to be found where one the only difference is prenasalization at the beginning of the word.

Comment: <x> is also [z] sometimes, especially word-initially. Also, which language is it that you mention in your last paragraph?

Comment: Contrary to your supposition, I believe there may be minimal pairs with [ð] and [θ] in English, they are just very rare for historical reasons to do with regular devoicing of word-final sibilants in OE, hence /bɑːθ/ and /beɪð/ in RP (not quite a minimal pair because of the vowel thing). I will see if I can think of a proper one.

Comment: Ah yes. Apparently in some varieties of English (which the wiktionary lists as chiefly American), <swath> may be pronounced /swɔθ/ for "a broad sweep or expanse" or /swɔð/ for "some kind of bandage".

Comment: There are *thigh* and *thy*. *Loath* and *loathe* are also a minimal pair for many people, though homophonous for others.

Comment: The term is voicing, but you seem to already know that...

Comment: For /ks/ v. /gz/: *ex* vs *eggs* in some dialects.I think your assumption that the contrasts you list aren't phonemic due to lack of minimal pairs may be mistaken

Comment: @curiousdannii the question is not about which phonological feature contrasts those two sounds, but whether there is a term for a presumably phonemic distinction that has no minimal pairs to strengthen the case for its existence, yet it's clearly also not allophones in free variation or predictably conditioned by the environment. I don't know if there is such a term but personally I think minimal pairs should be seen as an aid to show phonemicity, not as a thing that absolutely has to be there or else sounds are just allophones.

Comment: @LjL Right, I get what the question is about, but the actual question is literally asking about phonemes and voicing. Native speakers don't mix them up, despite the rarity of certain minimal pairs, because they're distinct phonemes. I'm not sure why any additional terminology would be helpful or useful here.

Comment: @Moss I think the "standard" English example of things that are normally considered distinct phonemes despite being in complementary distribution is /h/ vs /ŋ/. Maybe that's the one you were thinking of and not <x> vs <ng>? In this case the apparent contradiction is even stronger than with /θ/ vs /ð/, because there is not just a lack of minimal pairs contrasting them, but their choice *is* phonologically conditioned: you can know it's "sing" and not "sih", or conversely "hat" and not "ngat", even without knowing those specific words. Yet it still makes sense to consider them distinct phonemes.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't know if a specific term is warranted, but even though it may not happen in English, it doesn't strike me as unlikely that there could be languages where voicing distinctions are usually phonemic, but for one particular phoneme the voicing distinction is neutralized, becoming just allophonic. For instance, intervocalic /s/ vs /z/ in Italian is only consistently realized around Tuscany, while other places either use always /s/ or always /z/, and in some, it varies by individual: there are words (e.g. *disegno*) where I think I might use either in free variation.

Comment: @LjL I wasn't contrasting <x> with <ng>, if you read my question carefully. The term "complementary ditribution" is a good one related to this discussion, but actually, what I am asking about is kind of the opposite of that. I am talk about sounds or phonemes that occur in the same environment, but for some reason there are still no minimal pairs to prove that they contrast.

Comment: @Wilson The language I am studying is Tami. Spoken by about 2000 speakers in Papua New Guinea.

Comment: @Moss My bad. Anyway if someone really insisted that some sort of minimal pairs  are required to prove separate phonemic status, I guess we could develop some concept of "minimal pairs within the sound's influencing environment": in other words, if we know from other evidence that in English, generally, a syllable coda doesn't influence a syllable onset either diachronically or synchronically, then "thin" and "this" are minimal pairs because we know the difference between /n/ and /s/ has no influence on the sound of <th>. But ultimately I agree with others that minimal pairs aren't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are no terms that everyone agrees with. The thing you are talking about is phonemes, but where there are no minimal pairs that utterly prove phonemic status. Two sounds are "phonemes" if their distribution is not rule-governed. If we get rid of the few minimal pairs, the two fricatives still contrast. Some people might maintain that you need minimal pairs to utterly prove contrast, but lack of MPs has never been sufficient to prove contrast.

So there is no standard term for contrast without minimal pairs.

Answer (score 9):

Quick note, there are two minimal pairs for `[θ]` versus `[ð]` in English: *ether* ~ *either*, and *thigh* ~ *thy*.

But even if there aren't minimal pairs, a distinction can be phonemic **if it is unpredictable**. The distribution of `[ŋ]` versus `[ŋg]` can be predicted quite reliably:

- `[ŋ]` is used at the end of a morpheme (sing, sing-er)
- `[ŋg]` is used in the middle of a morpheme (finger, anger)

But the distribution of `[θ]` versus `[ð]` can't be. The best you can do is list all of the words with `[ð]` in them, and say "everything else has `[θ]`". Which is strong evidence that the two are separate phonemes, even if the words *ether* and *thy* drop out of the language entirely.

EDIT: Colin Fine has pointed out a few more minimal pairs: *mouth* (n) ~ *mouth* (v), *sooth* ~ *soothe*, and *wreath* ~ *wreathe*. Many thanks!

Comment: I think the logic that dictates minimal pairs cannot be an absolute requirement for attributing phonemic status to a pair of sounds can be seen by doing a mental experiment where minimal pairs exist, but then the words that form them stop being current, essentially disappearing from the language: *thy* is still understood and used in some very limited contexts, but let's say it disappears completely from any speaker's knowledge and that the *ether/either* pair doesn't exist... surely the accidental fact that an example showing contrast is now gone cannot, on its own, change phonemic status.

Comment: @LjL Indeed! Which is why the unpredictability of `[ð]` vs `[θ]` also makes them non-phonemic, even if people stop saying "ether" and "thy". I'll make that clearer.

Comment: Also _mouth_ (n) vs _mouth_ (v); _wreath_ vs _wreathe_, and _sooth_ vs _soothe_.

Comment: @ColinFine Oh, those are good ones! Want to write your own answer or should I add a PS?

Comment: @Draconis: go ahead.

Comment: Also 'backs' and 'bags' for minimal pair /ks/ vs gz/.

Comment: @Mitch True, though those are clusters, not individual phonemes; some analyses make `/ks/` an individual phoneme of English, which is sometimes realized as dental, sometimes palatal, sometimes voiced, sometimes voiceless, depending on morpheme boundaries. Compare the voicing in "sex-ual" against "luxury".

Comment: @Draconis Oh, right. I was just trying to relate to the pairs the OP gave.

Comment: What about "longer"? That segment is [ŋg] but would be [ŋ] according to your bullet points. Also consider that nouns end in [θ] always, a fairly reliable prediction from what I can tell

Comment: @Lorraine banger, hanger, clanger, bringer, clinger, ringer, singer, springer, stringer, swinger, wringer, and zinger all have [ŋ]. By contrast, younger, longer, and stronger have [ŋg]. It would appear the difference is front vs. back vowels. But then there is wronger with [ŋ], which doesn't fit the pattern.

Comment: @SamKauffman, An alternative analysis: the agentive suffix versus the comparative one. Do you analyse "wronger" as a noun or adjective? (genuine question; it's not a word in my variety of English)

Comment: @Lorraine, good point. I don't use "wronger" either, so I had to check a dictionary. Merriam-Webster has it as both a noun and an adjective, both with [ŋ]. If we discount the unusual usage as an adjective, then your analysis fits.